# Skype всегда clsCancelled

Tags: c#, .net, skype

Подскажите, почему у меня все время `call status = clsCancelled` ??  Пытаюсь просто сделать из *С#* кода вызов через *Skype*. Текстовые сообщения работают ок, но с вызовом не хочет. Вчера, когда уже закончились идеи - проверил под другим логином, на другого юзера в скайпе отправку, так сходу пошли события `clsRefused`, потом `clsRunning` вроде и осуществился дозвон. После чего обрадовался успеху, но повторные все варианты повторялись уже `clsCancelled` снова всегда и постоянно.... ((

```
Skype skype;
try
{
    skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
    if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
    {
        skype.Client.Start(true, true);
    }
    //skype.Attach(8, true);
    Call call = skype.PlaceCall("test-user-nickname");
    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine(call.Status + "   " + call.TransferStatus);
    } while (call.Status != TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода состояния skype лучше убрать `do { Thread.Sleep(); ... } while(...)`. 
Вместо этого надо подключиться к событиям, примерно так:

```
using SKYPE4COMLib;
// ...
var skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
// ...
skype.CallTransferStatusChanged += (s, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Status + " " + e);
};
```

или так:

```
skype.CallTransferStatusChanged += Skype_CallTransferStatusChanged;
// ...
private static void Skype_CallTransferStatusChanged(Call pCall, CallStatus Status) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Status + " " + e);
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что не удастся сделать вызов, ввиду прекращения поддержки? https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12322/is-skypekit-being-discontinued?q=SKYPE4COMLib

Comment: в 2013 прекратили, но есть пример - опубликован в сентябре 2014 -- [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/238363/)

Comment: В [этом](http://habrahabr.ru/post/238363/) примере бот обменивается только сообщениями, про вызовы нет ничего.